# Usage of 'in' in 'the series end in 4 games'

Tags: prepositions

I saw a sentence : The series end in 4 games. Does this sentence mean *the series end after 4 games*, or *the series end b4 games*, or *the series end at 4th game*?

Comment: That sentence is not coherent. If it was "The series end**s** in 4 games", it would mean "There are four more games from now, and then the series will be finished".

Comment: @ColinFine it could be the plural of "series", which is also "series".

Comment: @MaxWilliams. I suppose it could. Except that I have no idea what the sentence would mean with that interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means,

> The series ends at the fourth game. (precisely, the series ends exactly when the 4th game ends)

The correct way to say that it will end at some unknown/unspecified time, before the end of the fourth game is **"... within four games".**

If you say, "the series ends *after* four games", it's the same as "... in four games". If you want to be clear that it doesn't end *for sure* after the fourth game, say **"*... after four or more games*".**

---

This use of "in X" with a series of events, is the same as when 'in' is used for time periods: for example, 'in 3 minutes' means 180 seconds from now. There are some examples here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in , in the section marked "(DURING)"

Comment: Thank you! I have a additional question. 'The series ends after 4 games.' Is this sentence wrong? Plus, what's difference between this sentence and 'Then series ends in 4 games'?

Comment: Those two sentences mean the same: when game 4 ends, the series ends too!